# Has Trump managed to implement any of his anti-corruption (lobbying reform) campaign proposals?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, campaigning, corruption, lobbying

In a [2016 article](https://www.bbc.com/news/election-us-2016-37699073), the BBC noted some (four) proposals of then-candidate Trump:

> 1. Currently, anyone spending less than 20% of their time engaged in lobbying can call themselves an "adviser" or "consultant". Trump says this a loophole that must be closed.
> 2. The Republican candidate wants a five-year ban preventing government officials who have recently departed the government from immediately joining lobbying firms. And he wants a lifetime lobbying ban on any former administration officials who have previously worked on behalf of foreign governments.
> 3. He has called on Congress to change campaign finance laws to stop anyone who lobbies for foreign governments from raising funds for US elections.
> 4. "If I'm elected president, I will push for a constitutional amendment to impose term limits on all members of Congress," Mr Trump said, without specifying how long the new limits should be.

Did any of these take a more concrete form, e.g. law proposals or regulation changes after he was elected?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> 1. Currently, anyone spending less than 20% of their time engaged in lobbying can call themselves an "adviser" or "consultant". Trump says this a loophole that must be closed.

I couldn't find anything on this specifically.

---

> 2.The Republican candidate wants a five-year ban preventing government officials who have recently departed the government from immediately joining lobbying firms. And he wants a lifetime lobbying ban on any former administration officials who have previously worked on behalf of foreign governments.

This was put into effect [in 2017](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/01/29/trump-imposes-lifetime-ban-on-some-lobbying-five-years-for-others.html):

> President Donald Trump acted Saturday to fulfill a key portion of his pledge to “drain the swamp” in Washington, banning administration officials from ever lobbying the U.S. on behalf of a foreign government and imposing a separate five-year ban on other lobbying.

---

> 3. He has called on Congress to change campaign finance laws to stop anyone who lobbies for foreign governments from raising funds for US elections.

I couldn't find anything on this. The closest thing I could find was [52 U.S. Code § 30121](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30121):

> (a)Prohibition
>
> It shall be unlawful for—
>
> (1)a foreign national, directly or indirectly, to make—
>
> (A)a contribution or donation of money or other thing of value, or to make an express or implied promise to make a contribution or donation, in connection with a Federal, State, or local election;
>
> (B)a contribution or donation to a committee of a political party; or
>
> (C)an expenditure, independent expenditure, or disbursement for an electioneering communication (within the meaning of section 30104(f)(3) of this title); or
>
> (2)a person to solicit, accept, or receive a contribution or donation described in subparagraph (A) or (B) of paragraph (1) from a foreign national.
>
> (b)“Foreign national” definedAs used in this section, the term “foreign national” means—
>
> (1)a foreign principal, as such term is defined by section 611(b) of title 22, except that the term “foreign national” shall not include any individual who is a citizen of the United States; or
>
> (2)an individual who is not a citizen of the United States or a national of the United States (as defined in section 1101(a)(22) of title 8) and who is not lawfully admitted for permanent residence, as defined by section 1101(a)(20) of title 8.

However, this seems to have been around since [at least 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_52_of_the_United_States_Code), so this certainly doesn't count as something President Trump himself. It was already there.

---

> 4."If I'm elected president, I will push for a constitutional amendment to impose term limits on all members of Congress," Mr Trump said, without specifying how long the new limits should be.

Trump did push for this [in 2018](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/04/30/donald-trump-stance-on-congressional-term-limits-560641):

> President Donald Trump voiced his support on Monday for instituting congressional term limits, renewing calls for a proposal that he made a staple of his campaign pledge to “drain the swamp” in Washington.
>
> “I recently had a terrific meeting with a bipartisan group of freshman lawmakers who feel very strongly in favor of Congressional term limits,” the president tweeted. “I gave them my full support and endorsement for their efforts. #DrainTheSwamp”.

Though I struggle to call this "concrete."

---

So, I guess the answer is, "some of both." He did fulfill #2, but otherwise, I don't see any other laws or executive orders about other things specifically.

However, keep in mind that extending the definition of a lobbyist to people who lobby even less than 20% could have been in the 5 year ban order and nobody saw it. But I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Are there any numbers on how many people #2 affects?

Comment: @Jontia That was going to be my question. I think the article is referring to [Executive Order 13770](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Executive_Order_13770.pdf). There is a statement in the article claims that "Trump is allowed to waive all restrictions," which seems to be validated in Section 3. Do we know if any waivers have been given?

Comment: @Jontia Not that I found,

Comment: @JeffLambert Again, I didn't find any numbers on that either.

Comment: A bit of a necro comment, but it might be worth it to update the answer now that Trump has revoked the executive order mentioned in #2.